# Error when calculating long numbers in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to calculate the square root of some large numbers for example:

```
np.sqrt(324524513452345134623454326)
```

but I get the following error:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.sqrt(324524513452345134623454326)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'sqrt'
>>> np
<module 'numpy' from '/.../site-packages/numpy/__init__.py'>
>>> np.sqrt(324524)
569.6700799585669
```

Note: `np` is not an integer, it is bound to the `numpy` module still! For smaller integers, the function call works just fine.

I am using python 3.6.

Comment: Actually, I can reproduce this with `np`, will update the question for better readability.

Comment: That's weird, I am executing: import numpy as np; np.sqrt(3452348570324956867234965793468), I get same error. Yes sorry for the formatting I am new to this website.

Comment: This happens for any int >= 2 ** 64. `np.sqrt((1 << 64) - 1)` works, `np.sqrt((1 << 64))` does not.

Comment: The limit is almost certainly architecture dependent; on 32-bit systems the limit would be lower.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to enable working with these large numbers?

Comment: The work-around is to either use `float`, or use `math.sqrt()`. `numpy.sqrt()` only can work with native C types, and integers are limited to `unsigned long long` (8 bytes).

Comment: @MartijnPieters This work-around is not terribly helpful if arbitrary precision is required. A better solution would be to use [`gmpy`](https://github.com/aleaxit/gmpy) (or any other arbitrary precision library).

Comment: @norok2: feel free to add an answer to the duplicate then. However, note that for *Python integers*, `math.sqrt()` does not have the `numpy` limitation. Python's integers are arbitrary precision *already* without the need for an external library.

Comment: @MartijnPieters True for integer, but not for floats which is what you are going to get after the `sqrt()`, and for large enough numbers, this is going to hit limits of the floating point representation.

Comment: @norok2: sure, but that's not the question here.